# Reading alphanumeric config value from spring boot application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

I am trying to read cron expression from application.yml in spring boot,but i am getting below error

Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning an alias
 in 'reader', line 32, column 16:
        batchfreq: */5 * * * *
expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found /

in application yml
batchfreq: */5 * * * *

```
@Scheduled(cron="${services.dmt.batchfreq}")
public  void update(){}
```

Comment: yaml doesn't actually like having the first character asterisks (*)

Answer (score 4):

I resolved above error by changing cron expresssion from */5 * * * * to "*/5 * * * *",the issue may be due to space in between value.

Comment: This resolved my problem as well. But it is sad that it isn't clear why this happening. Anyways thank you for sharing your solution!